# Remove item with duplicate ID from multidimensional array with criterion which to keep

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of hiking trails where each trail has an ID and a list of coordinates, like this:

```
[{id:10, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
{id:20, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
{id:30, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
{id:10, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 63}]},
{id:50, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]}]
```

I want to remove duplicate items, meaning items with the same ID, but keeping the item where the list of coordinates is longer.

It's no problem for me to remove an item with the same ID, but I do not know how to define which one of the items is kept. I assume it always is the first item that is kept.

This is waht I tried. I want to check which of the coordinates is longer and then keep this one and remove the other one.

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 for(let j = i + 1; j < array.length; ) {
  if(array[i].id === array[j].id && array[i].coordinates.length > array[j].coordinates.length)
    array.splice(j, 1);
  else if(array[i].id === array[j].id && array[i].geometry.coordinates.length < array[j].geometry.coordinates.length)
    array.splice(i, 1);
 else
  j++;
 }
}
```

Comment: `{15, 69}` Your input's syntax is invalid. Objects need key-value pairs.

Comment: by longer coordinates you mean length of the array?

Comment: yes exactly, I mean those with a longer coordinates list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in a concise way via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and some ES6 destructuring:

```js
const data = [{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,63]]},{id:20,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:30,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:50,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {id, coords}) => {
  r[id] = (r[id] || []).length < coords.length ? {id, coords} : r[id]
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

You can also have it in a less readable on one line variant:

```js
const data = [{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,63]]},{id:20,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:30,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:50,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {id, coords}) => 
 (r[id] = (r[id] || []).length < coords.length ? {id, coords} : r[id]) && r, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //If you sort it .
 [{id:10, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
 {id:10, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 63}]},
 {id:20, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
 {id:30, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]},
 {id:50, coords:[{15, 69}, {16, 85}, {16, 34}]}]
  //Loop downwards and check if it's the same id and > coordinates length than previous 
  // just remove the previous.
 let i,j,id;
if(array.length!=0)
{
j=0;
id=array[j].id;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  while(id==array[i].id&& i<array.length)
  {
      if(array[i].cordinates.length< array[j].cordinates.length)
      {
         array.splice(i, 1);
       i--;
      }
     else
      {
        array.splice(j, 1);
        j=i;
      }
     i++;
  }
   j=i;
   id=array[j].id;
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get unique items per `id` based on the length of `coords` array like this:

```js
const input = [{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:10,coords:[[15,69],[16,63]]},{id:20,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:30,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]},{id:50,coords:[[15,69],[16,85],[16,34]]}]

const merged = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.id] || o.coords.length > acc[o.id].coords.length)
    acc[o.id] = o;
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```